Go Endpoint doesn't call handler Method
I'm implementing a small hobby project with Go, HTMX, Templ as TechStack. Because I'm new to it, I started a small playground and try to build some small search.
Now I'm facing the issue, that my handler method is only called once at beginning:
package main

    import (
        "net/http"
    
        "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5"
    )
    
    func main() {
        router := chi.NewRouter()
    
        router.Get("/", indexHandler().ServeHTTP)
        router.Get("/employee_search", employeeSearchHandler().ServeHTTP)
        http.ListenAndServe(":3000", router)
    }

The basic idea is, that if someone is searching in a search-box the employeeSearchHandler is updating the UI to show some results.
At the moment the handler is only generating a random number:
func employeeSearchHandler() *templ.ComponentHandler {
    var employee = rand.IntN(1000)
    fmt.Println(employee)
    return templ.Handler(employee_search.EmployeeResult(employee))
}

My Template looks like this:
templ EmployeeSearch() {

        <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Suchen" aria-label="Search" autocomplete="off"
            hx-get="/employee_search"
            hx-trigger="input delay:500ms changed"
            hx-target="#employee_result"
            hx-swap="innerHTML" />
    
        <div id="employee_result">
        </div>
    }

Now I'm wondering that my browser shows a new request every time I'm typing and stopping for 500ms as expected, but it returns always the exact same HTML. The random number isn't changing. I see this behaviour also in Server Console. The number is generated on startup and afterwards it's never created again. Even the HTMX event is firing, but it just send back the same HTML all the time.
What do I oversee here?


In Go F() is a call expression that's evaluated then and there and only as many times as it's calling code is executed. The function main, which is the calling code of the employeeSearchHandler() expression, is executed only once, regardless of how many requests your program accepts. In other words, your expectations are quite misplaced.

@mkopriva ok i see, thank you :). But I don‘t understand how this should work then…

I figured it out:
in main.go it looks like this now:
func main() {
    router := chi.NewRouter()

    //router.Get("/", indexHandler().ServeHTTP)
    router.Get("/employee_search", employeeSearchHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", router)
}

So I don't call the method employeeSearchHandler and just pass the func as argument. The handler itself is then passing the Response, Request objects:
func employeeSearchHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var employee = rand.IntN(1000)
    templ.Handler(employee_search.EmployeeResult(employee)).ServeHTTP(w, r)
}

This way it's updating on every route call as I would expect :)
